# Move a file to a new folder after it has been renamed

Tags: vbscript, file-rename, file-move

I require a VBScript that renames a file and then moves it from one folder to another.  The script currently renames the file correctly, but I cannot figure out how to move the file to the new folder after the renaming.

Below is the script as it exists.

```
Option Explicit

Const SAVE_LOCATION = "\\pccit2\Int\PC\Inbox"
Const strPath       = "D:\Files\pak\VP\"
Const StrPrefix     = "VP"

Dim FSO
Dim FLD
Dim fil
Dim strOldName
Dim strNewName

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each fil In FLD.Files
    strOldName = fil.Path
    strNewName = strPath & strPrefix & Right(strOldName, 10)
    FSO.MoveFile strOldName, strNewName
Next

For Each fil In FLD.Files
    If strNewName = 1 Then
        FSO.MoveFile "\\pccit2\Int\PC\Inbox"
    End If
Next

Set FLD = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

I have tried a variety ways of getting the file to move.  Here are some other attempts:

```
If FSO.FileExists("D:\Files\pak\VP\*.*") Then
    FSO.MoveFile "D:\Files\pak\VP\*.*", "\\pccit2\Int\PC\Inbox\*.*"
End If
```

Another attempt

```
If fil.FileExists("D:\Files\pak\VP\*.*") Then
    fil.MoveFile "D:\Files\pak\VP\*.*" , "\\pccit2\Int\PC\Inbox\*.*"
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MoveFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcf3ba6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is a method of the `FileSystemObject` object. It expects at least 2 arguments (source and destination), and wildcards can only be used in the source path, *not* in the destination path. The destination must be a file or folder path (with a trailing backslash if it's a folder). The respective method of file objects is [`Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxtftw67%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), which can be called with just one argument (the destination path). Also, you can move and rename a file in one step. Just specify the destination path with the new file name.

```
For Each fil In FLD.Files
    strNewName = FSO.BuildPath(SAVE_LOCATION, strPrefix & Right(fil.Name, 10))
    fil.Move strNewName
Next
```

If you want to separate renaming from moving you can rename the file by simply changing its name:

```
For Each fil In FLD.Files
    fil.Name = strPrefix & Right(fil.Name, 10)
    fil.Move SAVE_LOCATION & "\"
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! This has been extremely helpful and I will reference your response going forward.  The first script you provided worked perfectly. Only modification was to add in the VP for a prefix.  Which I did by adding it here.

strNewName = FSO.BuildPath(SAVE_LOCATION, **"VP"** & Right(fil.Name, 10))

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
dim fs
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.MoveFile "c:\myfolder\*.*","c:\anotherfolder\"
set fs=nothing
```

Comment: I have modified the script as you have indicated, I now get this error  "Variable is undefined:  'Server' " for this line:
     set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Comment: I don't think he's using ASP at all. What gave you the idea? In regular VBScript you'd simply use `Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`.